# get value of div class in jquery drop event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, I am trying to capture and display the value of a div class when it is 'dropped'.
For example, I want to display '01:20' when this particular element is dropped.
div class='routineTime'>01:20 /div>

Additionaly, I want to sum and display a running total of these dropped elements.

I have an example in jsfiddle, but it's only displaying the 'routineTime' of the first element
that is dropped. I need to sum and display 'routineTime' for each element that is dropped.

http://jsfiddle.net/n2learning/QfFQ9/9/

Appreciate any help!

DK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a iterator for all the dropped elements inside the drop able section.

```
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $('#info').find("h1").remove();

        var tmp, routineTime = [0, 0];
        $('.routineTime', $(this)).each (function () {
            tmp = $(this).text().split(':');

            if ($.trim(tmp[0]) == '') tmp[0] = 0;

            routineTime [0] += parseInt(tmp[0], 10);
            routineTime [1] += parseInt(tmp[1], 10);               
        });

        routineTime [0] += parseInt(routineTime [1]/60);
        routineTime [1] = routineTime[1]%60;

        $('#calcTime').html(routineTime [0] + ':' + routineTime [1]);

    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QfFQ9/12/)

<s>The addTime logic has its own complexity... which you need to implement inside the `$.each`</s>

**Edit:** Added addTime logic.. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Wow Vega, you nailed it! Very intuitive with regards to minutes and seconds. I appreciate this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your drop event handler, you just need to iterate the collection of all elements in the target frame rather than using the vague selector.

```
var routineTime;

$('#dropTargetframe .routineTime').each(function() {

    //Example used here, use your own time library.
    routineTime += Foo.GetTimeValue($(this).html()); 

});

$('#calcTime').text(routineTime);
```